# Create and store HTML file in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to create **HTML file** in ios Programmatically. How should I create HTML file and store it in to Document directory?

Comment: You've asked a similar question moments ago and it got closed due to not enough detail.  If you want people to help you, you'll need to post something that someone can answer.  Here's some hints - give a bit of background - say what you've tried - say what experience you've got; anything more would be helpful - you'll find that there are a lot of good people here who are willing to help, but you've got to put the effort in also.

Comment: Again wrong question - [Previous Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662927/how-should-i-create-html-file-in-ios).
Please make your question clear and specific so that we can help you.

Comment: @nidhish... If you want `File I/O` in iOS then search for tutorial on `Google`

Comment: i have uitableview in which i have displayed data in Uitableview. I want to make HTML file from that data.

Answer (score 3):

this a way to create a file in document directory

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentDirectory,@"index.html"];

 NSData *data=[@"<html><body>hai</body></html>" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```